# table.rows[index].scrollIntoView() not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to scroll into a particular row of a table; the `div` along with the `table` inside it, both have `overflow:auto`. This is my code for scrolling to a particular index of the table:

```
var table1 = document.getElementById("old_table");
table1.rows[3].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'center'
});
```

This is my **html**:

```
<div id="old_slab"><table id="old_table" border="2"></table></div>
```

And my **css**:

```
#old_slab{
  position: absolute;
  top:34em;
  left:30em;
  width:40em;
  height: 15em;
  overflow: auto; 
}

#old_table{
  height: 15em;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 40em;
}
```

*The rows in my table are dynamically created, hence they are not hardcoded in my html code. Nevertheless, the table isn't empty*. For some reason, the `scrollIntoView()` isn't working and I don't know why. Please help.

**EDIT:** Strangely, when I remove the `behaviour` and `block` arguments, then it works:

```
table1.rows[3].scrollIntoView(true);
```

Comment: Maybe call scrollIntoView on the contents of a row, i.e. `table1.rows[3].cells[0].firstChild.scrollIntoView(...)`

Comment: Please try to use a callback after dynamically creating rows. As far as I could check your code works if table is static - https://codepen.io/alekskorovin/pen/yLodYVM

Comment: You should run the scrollIntoView method only after DOM was updated by the dynamic function.

Comment: Yes, only after the table rows being updated, does the `scrollIntoView()..` method run. I've checked it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `.scrollIntoView()` works on a properly referenced element whether dynamic added or not. The example below has 2 buttons proving it.

```js
const scrollToRow = (selector, index) => {
  const table = document.querySelector(selector);
  const row = table.rows;
  row[index].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'center'
  });
};

document.querySelector('.scroll').onclick = function(e) {
  scrollToRow('table', 3);
}

/* The following code is to simulate
dynamically added rows */

const addRow = selector => {
  const table = document.querySelector('table');
  const row = table.insertRow(0);
  const cell = row.insertCell(0);
  cell.colSpan = 2;
};

document.querySelector('.add').onclick = function() {
  addRow('table');
};
```

```css
section {
  width: 40em;
  height: 15em;
  padding: 10%
}

table {
  height: 15em;
  width: 40em;
  border: 2px solid black
}

td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

td::before {
   content: '\a0';
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 30%;
}
```

```html
<button class='add'>Add Row</button>
<button class='scroll'>Scroll to Row 4</button>
<section>
<table>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<section>
```